# .Net MySql error "The given key was not present in the dictionary"

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

Trying to get simple count from table results in exception bellow.
Tried different select statemens which also makes exception: "`SELECT * FROM goods`", but "`SELECT col1, col2 FROM goods`" - works without exception. What am I doing wrong? From workbench these selects works.

> The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>   System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not
>   present in the dictionary.    at
>   System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.get_Item(TKey key)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlField.SetFieldEncoding()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnData(MySqlField field)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.GetColumnsData(MySqlField[]
>   columns)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.GetColumns(Int32 count)
>   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet.LoadColumns(Int32 numCols)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.ResultSet..ctor(Driver d, Int32 statementId,
>   Int32 numCols)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.NextResult(Int32
>   statementId, Boolean force)    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.Close()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ResetReader()    at
>   MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
>   behavior)    at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
>   at MySqlSybaseComparer.DbTester.Test(String& error) in
>   c:\MySqlSybaseComparer\DbTester.cs:line 68

code snippet:

```
using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(ConStrMySql))
{
    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM goods", conn))
        {
            using (MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                    MessageBox.Show(reader[0].ToString());
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.ToString(););
    }
    conn.Close();
}
```

Connection string to DB: `Server=localhost; Database=art; Uid=ramunas; Pwd=xxxx; AllowUserVariables=True;`

Comment: when u have only a count(*) which will be an integer variable it would be better using executeScalar   Int32 count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());

Comment: ExecuteScalar throws exception also.

Comment: I hope there would be a table called goods and u are specifying the correct database name in your web config please try this also select isnull(count(*),0) from goods and use ExecuteScalar

Comment: isnull(count(*),0) - is not leagal in mysql, anyway count() should never return null. I hardcoded my connection string into code, and since i can get readout from database i am sure connection string is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code is correct and all suggestion also should work. Just removed "collation-server" settings and restarted server and everything works as expected.

[image]

Answer (score 29):

### Year 2017

I have solved your same error simply adding the charset to the connection string:

```
Server=myServer;Port=3306;Database=myDB15;User ID=usr33;Password=usr33P;CharSet=utf8;
```

In my case I'm using *MySql Connector for .Net version 6.9.3*. to connect to 30 equal databases with the same structure, same collation (*utf8_unicode_ci*) and different table contents.

When I use the *MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()* method to select content from *user* table, in some databases (4 of 30) a got the same error *The given key was not present in the dictionary*.

### Year 2022

Some years later I had the same problem with *ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery()*, but right now using *MySql.Data* and *MySql.Data.EntityFramework* both on version 8.0.27 and when migrating a database from MySQL 5.7.38 to 8.0.28 or 8.0.30.

Adding *CharSet* or *Allow User Variables* to the connection string didn't work (and it wasn't possible to change my SELECT or Server settings).

**Only updating *MySql.Data* and *MySql.Data.EntityFramework* to version 8.0.30 solved the problem**.

Comment: `MySql.Data.EntityFramework` is deprecated. Use `MySql.EntityFrameworkCore` instead

Answer (score 5):

After spending 5 hours researching how to fix it!!!.. i finally figured it out... all you need to do is to make sure that your 'MySql.Data.dll' is up to date! you can download it somewhere. or you can find it here C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Installer for Windows\MySql.Data.dll.. :D

Comment: some time it may required .Net 4.5.2 or upper version

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
SELECT count(*) as count FROM goods
```

Answer (score 1):

In place of this statement:

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT count(*) FROM goods", conn))
```

Use:

```
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM goods", conn))
```

and then convert it to int value by using ExecuteScalar(). Something like this:

```
int count = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Comment: Are you getting the same error by using this statement also?

Comment: try cmd.Connection.Open(); before converting it to Int32.

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem using .net core 2.1, mysql, nhibernate.

After i added `"Allow User Variables=True"` to connection string in appsettings.json my problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with the error "the given key '0' was not found in the dictionary", it seems it's looking for the MySQL DLL. Adding MySql.Data through your package manager or adding the DLL manually from the connector should solve it.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all of these answers and none helped me.
I eventually tracked it down. The message was that .NET does not support the characterset (in my case utf8mb3) that the database was reporting.
Changed the default charset of the database and it worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Do update your mysql connector for .net, Then remove the old reference mysql.data.dll in your application project and add the updated one from program files(x86)/mysql/MySQL Connector Net 8.0.26\Assemblies\v4.5.2\MySql.Data.dll

Answer (score 0):

You may try going to "Server explorer" and delete the instance of your server that you are trying to connect. Once the instance is deleted trying connecting to the database once again with correct credentials. And if you are working with ADO.NET model be careful the versions of component that you are installing and referencing.

Answer (score 0):

To get compatability you will need to use specific versions of the MySql.EntityFrameworkCore, MySql Connector/NET and entity framework to avoid these issues.

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-entityframework-core-scaffold-example.html for examples

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="6.0.10">
        <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
        <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="MySql.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="6.0.4" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Update the entity framework tool with

```
dotnet tool update --global dotnet-ef
```

The scaffolding command should look like

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=[Host];Database=[DBName];User Id=[Username];Password=[Password];" MySql.EntityFrameworkCore -o [OutputContextName] --no-pluralize --no-onconfiguring -f
```

For details check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet and search for **dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold**

Answer (score 0):

use Database name in your query and Port in connection String

```
strMySqlConnection = 
   "server=localhost;Port=3306; user id=root; password=; database=art; 
    pooling=false;Charset = utf8 ;";
SELECT * FROM goods ==> SELECT * FROM `art`.`goods`
```

Update MySql.Data & use .Netframework 4.6

Answer (score 0):

As of 2023, updating MySqlData.dll to the latest using the Nuget or offline installation is the only fix for this.

Answer (score -1):

in my case i use MySQL Connector NET 6.3.0 and the solution that i got is to change connection string key

from

```
Server=127.0.0.1;Uid=root;Pwd=xxxx;Database=dbname;CharSet=utf8
```

to this

```
server=127.0.0.1;user id=root;password=xxxx;database=dbname;charset=utf8;pooling=false
```

Comment: Turning off connection pooling has significant performance implications. Never do this.